# UILocalNotification repeating itself after some time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am using `UILocalNotification` when a user enters a region or leaves it (Geofencing) to prompt the user. Everything is working fine except this scenario "When i leave the location i prompt the user like **Thanks for Visiting**, i cleared the notification centre. Now after two hours i got a prompt **Thanks for Visiting** i checked in notification centre the time of the notification was not **Now** instead it was **2h ago**".

I am not using any repetition of `UILocalNotification` anybody knows why this is happening?

Comment: Is it possible the user moved to a different time zone?

Comment: No that doesn't happened

Answer (score 0):

I posted this issue to apple they said this issue has been addressed in ios7 beta 1.